# Extract phone number from text using re?

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract phone number, but my regex don't extract all numbers

```
text = '+79082343434   8(912)2342554,  +7 982 342 sdfdsf 34 34 fsf 8-923-132-34-23 +7 982 342 34 34! sdfsd'
r = re.compile(r"\+?\d{1,3}?[- .]?\(?(?:\d{2,3})\)?[- .]?\d\d\d[- .]?\d\d\d\d")
phone = r.findall(text)

Out[7]: ['+79082343434', '8(912)2342554']
```

Desire output:

```
['+79082343434', '8(912)2342554', '8-923-132-34-23', '+7 982 342 34 34']
```

How can I improve this expression to get all phone numbers?

Comment: If they are formatted well, see http://ideone.com/MQpoeR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the output you want:

```
text = '+79082343434   8(912)2342554,  +7 982 342 sdfdsf 34 34 fsf 8-923-132-34-23 +7 982 342 34 34! sdfsd'
regex = re.compile("\+?\d[\( -]?\d{3}[\) -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{2}[ -]?\d{2}")
numbers = re.findall(regex, text)
```

But you might need to fine tune the expression a bit, depending on exactly what you want to consider a phone number.

Comment: Can you say, how can I ignore this combinations? `0015-002-2012, 13999947069'  and others?

Comment: People used to use 00 instead of + in Europe, and 001 is "+" in the US, so you might not want to ignore this. In France all national phone numbers start with a single 0 (01... - 09..., where 06... & 07... are mobile).In Germany phone numbers are of the form (0xxx) yyy (with or without parentheses) or +zzz (xxx) yyy, where 0xxx is a "city prefix" which you can omit if you are nearby, and where yyy could comprise spaces or sometimes '-' (esp. for extensions in firms and administrations)

Answer (score 1):

This should find all the phone numbers in a given string

re.findall(r'+?(?[1-9][0-9 .-()]{8,}[0-9]', text)

```
 >>> re.findall(r'[\+\(]?[1-9][0-9 .\-\(\)]{8,}[0-9]', text)
 ['+79082343434   8(912)2342554', '8-923-132-34-23', '+7 982 342 34 34']
```

Basically, the regex lays out these rules

1. The matched string may start with + or ( symbol
2. It has to be followed by a number between 1-9
3. It has to end with a number between 0-9
4. It may contain 0-9 (space) .-() in the middle.